# Cannot connect to server via Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

(I am new to all this so please bear with me :)

I want to connect to my Server 2003 machine via my desktop XP Pro machine.  They both belong to the same Workgroup: MSHOME - but I always get the error message from **Remote Desktop Connection** whenever I try to connect by browsing for computers and I click on the node "MSHOME":

> The MSHOME domain/workgroup does not
>   contain any Terminal servers.

I know I can connect by just putting in the name of the server machine and password - but it would be nice to browse the domain/workgroup - what do I need to do to put this right?

Cheers

PS - What exactly is a terminal server anyway - why is it complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminal Server is the name of the service on the 2003 server that handles remote desktops requests. When you're doing remote desktop, you're actually trying to contact this service.

This support article by Microsoft explains what to do:
[Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 Are Not Advertised as Terminal Services Servers](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;281307)

Just take all normal precautions before updating the registry, such as creating a system restore point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Browse feature you could try the steps in [MS KB 281307](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281307).

Excerpt here:

*To cause a computer that is running Windows XP Professional or Windows Server 2003, but is not configured as a Terminal Services server, to advertise itself as a Terminal Services server:*

1. Start Registry Editor (Regedit.exe).
2. Locate and then click the following registry key:
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
3. Change the value of the TSAdvertise DWORD value from 0 to 1.
4. Quit Registry Editor.
5. Restart the computer.

Note Windows Server 2003-based computers that are configured as Terminal Services servers, and Windows 2000 Server-based servers or Windows 2000 Advanced Server-based servers with Terminal Services installed in either Application Server mode or in Remote Administration mode already have the TSAdvertise registry value set to 1. Therefore, these servers advertise themselves as Terminal Services servers.